# Set status as pass if green else fail while comparing two excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I want to append a column (Status) in my Excel based on cell color.

If all cell of that row is green then the Status should be PASS else FAIL.

I am using the below code

```
import pandas as pd

from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = "Excel_Diff.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(filename)

sheet_name = "Sheet1"

ws = wb[sheet_name]

data = ws.values

columns = next(data)[1:]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

status_column = []

for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):

    green = all(cell.fill.fgColor.rgb == "FF00FF00" for cell in row)
    
    status_column.append("pass" if green else "fail")

df["status"] = status_column
```

but this is not working.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: You're on a good path to a good question. Perhaps you could create a small code chunk that generates the Excel file which demonstrates the problem. In addition, you could expand on what is the result and what you expect instead. Perhaps give a hypothesis why you think it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you use `ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)`.  This kwarg means that only the values of all the cells are taken, so they are strings.  If you remove this, you can see the difference in what is returned:

```py
[row for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)]
#Out[]: 
#[('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'),
# ('Red', 1, 0.95396020076544, 0.29105030184105374),
# ('Green', 2, 0.35323937340945766, 0.32459389966476326),
# ('Red', 3, 0.3648347692956413, 0.6750402635446109),
# ('Blue', 4, 0.562487643312757, 0.35390177206328044),
# ('Red', 5, 0.8456327417471485, 0.08121976975519996)]

[row for row in ws.iter_rows()]
#Out[]: 
#[(<Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D1>),
# (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A2>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B2>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C2>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D2>),
# (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A3>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B3>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C3>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D3>),
# (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A4>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B4>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C4>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D4>),
# (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A5>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B5>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C5>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D5>),
# (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A6>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B6>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C6>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D6>)]
```

Then, as you now have the ***cells*** and not the ***cell values***, you can use your code:

```py
status_column = []
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    green = all(cell.fill.fgColor.rgb == "FF00FF00" for cell in row)
    status_column.append("pass" if green else "fail")
status_column
#Out[]: ['fail', 'fail', 'pass', 'fail', 'fail', 'fail']
```